# How to get files opened in Firefox 3.0, instead of only being saved?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, media

I currently use Firefox 3.0, under Ubuntu 9.04, and whenever a picture, media file, or MP3 file is attached on my web mail, all I can do is actually SAVE the file, Firefox does not give me the option to just open it in a new window/program. Once the file is saved, I can then manually open it from the download manager. With the same version under Windows, I have no problem getting the file opened directly from Firefox.

What do I need to change in my settings to allow such option in Firefox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Open in Browser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8207) Firefox extension.

Comment: Great ! I wanna try this !

Answer (score 1):

Tools -> Options -> Applications

Here is settings for each file type.

[image]